# Divs are hidden in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-float

This code works fine with IE and Firefox but for some reason, most of the divs will not show in Chrome. Not sure what I am missing here. there is a lot of html and css so I am including just a snippet here with a link. Any help letting me know my mistakes would be greatly appreciated

https://jsfiddle.net/Dude_Abides/Lau6qg1b/

```
<div class="left">
<div class="articleHeader">
<h3 class="articleHeaderContent">President's Corner</h3>
</div><!-- end articleHeader -->

<img src="images/000-BillyElliott.jpg" alt="Author Pic" style="height:100px; width:100px;" class="authorPic">

<br>

<div class="authorHeader">
<p class="authorName">Billy Elliott</p>
<br>
<p class="authorTitle">President</p>
</div><!-- end authorHeader -->

<br>

<p class="aP">If you have been with the company long, I'm sure you've heard we have a goal of 15% growth in gross profit each year. As a company we have no debt and have excess capital to invest in growth. So what's slowing us down? Figuring out where we should put in new locations is easy, finding or building a new building is not that difficult, and inventory is pretty straight forward. The hardest part is finding the right people.</p>

<p class="aP">It depends on the size of the location, but typically we need a store manager, maybe an operations manager, counter and inside sales people, warehouse and delivery people. We would prefer to promote from within. We like giving people who work for us the first chance at new opportunities, and it's easier to start a new branch with people who already know what they're doing. We find that even when we hire individuals who have experience in our industry but from outside <span class="store">Elliott Electric</span>, there is still a learning curve to doing things our way.</p>

<p class="aP">It seems like it should be easier to find people. We already know who works for us. But yet we still have a hard time identifying people who are interested in taking on a new challenge. In most cases it would require a move because we are opening up in a new town. With over 1600 employees, it makes it difficult to know who might be interested in moving and if so, where. Of course you might not be interested this year because your kid(s) may be graduating this year, but next year or the year after that you might be interested. In some cases we need someone fully qualified and other times we can take someone with limited experience but shows the drive to learn and willingness to take on a new challenge. We post job opportunities on our website and we send out companywide emails, but we still seem to get limited responses. I don't have a solution to the problem, but my suggestion is: if you're someone interested in moving up then you need to keep putting a bug in your manager's ear so when opportunities come up everyone will know you're a candidate. If you have any suggestions, please don't be shy!</p>
</div><!-- end left -->
```

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] in the question, not link to a wall of code on a third-party site

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll work a better format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using pseudo selectors like `::-webkit-scrollbar`. Chrome will handle it, other browser will ignore that line. So remove the lines with these selectors and it will work.

[See updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lau6qg1b/2/).